# Get single field from aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

please - help:

I have an aggregate result like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "person_id" : 416688
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "person_id" : 415722
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "person_id" : 415721
    }
}
```

I need to have this flatten like below:

```
/* 1 */
{
        "person_id" : 416688
}

/* 2 */
{
        "person_id" : 415722
}

/* 3 */
{
        "person_id" : 415721
}
```

Any idea how to get this done? - Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy susing `$project`. Add this stage at the end of your aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "person_id": "$_id.person_id"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X8cGhr-bIDd)